# Max element/size of a numpy matrix?

Tags: python, windows, memory-management, matrix, numpy

what is the max element/case of a numpy matrix or what is the maximal size of a numpy matrix?

the code above returns memory error at variable matrix size...so from what environmental thing does it depend (number of sequential amount of memory available?)?

```
for ret in xrange(5000,7000,50):

   res = []
   for x in xrange(ret):
       temp=[]
       for y in xrange(ret):
           temp.append(random.random())
       res.append(temp)

  print "r"
  r = numpy.mat(res)
  print "s"
  s = numpy.mat(res,dtype='f4')
  print "t"
  w = numpy.mat(res,dtype('f8'))
```

question: when and why did it return "memory error"?

ps: i use last python and numpy available on windows (yes I know...) 7 64bit.

Comment: `res` is overridden in each loop. I think this was not your intention? Your last line is wrong, it should be `w = numpy.mat(res,dtype='f8')`. If `ret` is not overridden in your original code it is possible that you get a MemoryError because the resulting list is to big.

Comment: Your inner two loops can be replaced by `r = np.random.random((ret, ret))`

Comment: Also, your memory error is probably coming from the lists you're building, not numpy. Making a numpy array using nested lists will use much, much more memory than just making it directly. 7000x7000 is not very big at all.

Answer (score 1):

See [Upper memory limit?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4285185/python-memory-limit).

As for when it returned a memory error, the answer is when allocating memory for one of the large objects. It could be any one, because you'll be at a higher amount of memory than ever before by the time you allocate the later rows of `res`, since the numpy matrixes don't get garbage collected until after you've pointed `r`, `s`, or `t` at another object (the new matrix created on the next iteration).