# Memory error on large Shapefile in Python

Tags: python, shapefile, pyshp

```
import shapefile
data = shapefile.Reader("data_file.shp")
shapes = data.shapes()
```

My problem is that getting the shapes from the Shapefile reader gives me an exception `MemoryError` when using [Pyshp](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pyshp).

The `.shp` file is quite large, at 1.2 gB. But I am using ony 3% of my machine's 32gB, so I don't understand it.

Is there any other approach that I can take? Can process the file in chunks in Python? Or use some tool to spilt the file into chinks, then process each of them individually?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although I haven't been able to test it, Pyshp should be able to read it regardless of the file size or memory limits. Creating the `Reader` instance doesn't load the entire file, only the header information.

It seems the problem here is that you used the `shapes()` method, which reads all shape information into memory at once. This usually isn't a problem, but it is with files this big. As a general rule you should instead use the `iterShapes()` method which reads each shape one by one.

```
import shapefile
data = shapefile.Reader("data_file.shp")
for shape in data.iterShapes():
    # do something...
```

Comment: I Can conform that the problem was not with the creation of the object, but with the `shapes()` method. However, the problem was that I was using 32 bit Python, which can only address 32gB RAM. When I installed the 64 bot version, the problem went away. However, if the `iterShapes()` method only loads a single shape into memory at a time then, of course, I will use that

Answer (score 3):

Quoting from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5537618/memory-errors-and-list-limits) by thomas:

> The `MemoryError` exception that you are seeing is the direct result of running out of available RAM. This could be caused by either the 2GB per program limit imposed by Windows ([32bit programs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa366778%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#memory_limits)), or lack of available RAM on your computer. (This [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4285185/python-memory-limit) is to a previous question). You should be able to extend the 2GB by using 64bit copy of Python, provided you are using a 64bit copy of windows.

So try a 64bit copy of Python or provide more detail about your platform and Python versions.

Comment: Despite possibly being right, this is more a comment than an answer... One line and half that is a question?

Comment: I haven't enough rating to comment but i still want to help

Comment: Nick, you might be right. How do I tell? when I run the interperter, I see `Python 2.7.11 (v2.7.11:6d1b6a68f775, Dec  5 2015, 20:32:19) [MSC v.1500 32 bit (Intel)] on win32`

Comment: This question gave me the answer, and, yes, I only have 32 bit (d'oh!). thanks, Nick, and welcome to the site hwere we are not supposed to say "thanks" :-/   See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1405913/how-do-i-determine-if-my-python-shell-is-executing-in-32bit-or-64bit-mode-on-os

Comment: @nick_gabpe Sorry if i sounded like a jerk, I did upvote but still think the answer deserves some improvement.

Comment: @paulo-scardine feel free to improve it.